# Pandas - fillna with subset of rows

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

I'm trying to fill some rows with 0s where a certain condition applies. I'm trying:

```
df.loc[:,(df.Available == True) & (df.Intensity.isnull())].Intensity = df.loc[(df.Available == True) & (df.Intensity.isnull())].Intensity.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

This doesn't work bc `IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series key provided`, but when I just try

```
df.loc[(df.Available == True) & (df.Intensity.isnull())].Intensity = df.loc[(df.Available == True) & (df.Intensity.isnull())].Intensity.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

That registers as updating a copy. How can I do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you don't even need `fillna` if you're already addressing the rows where Intensity is null.

```
df.loc[(df.Available) & (df.Intensity.isnull()), 'Intensity'] = 0
```

Alternatively you could do

```
df.loc[df.Available, 'Intensity'] = df.loc[df.Available, 'Intensity'].fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC:

```
df.query('Available == True')['Intensity'].fillna(0)
```

Comment: You have to assign it back.

Answer (score 2):

I broke this into several lines for readability

```
a = df.Available == True
b = df.Intensity.isnull()
df.loc[(a & b), 'Intensity'] = 0
```

However, this should also work

```
a = df.Available == True
b = df.Intensity.isnull()
df.Intesity *= (a & b)
```